# No class files specified. When jacoco test coverage

Tags: kotlin, jacoco

I would like to use Jacoco to generate a code coverage report on all my tests. So I implemented this in *build.gradle*

```
plugins {
   // some plugins
    id("jacoco")
}

android {
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        // some configurations here
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            enableUnitTestCoverage = true
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    // Added Jacoco here
    testCoverage {
        jacocoVersion = "0.8.7"
    }
    packaging {
        resources.excludes += "DebugProbesKt.bin"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
        compose = true
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.isReturnDefaultValues = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
}
```

And created a separated jacoco.gradle file for it's implementation. This is to ensure clean code and better readability.

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.7"

    afterEvaluate {
        afterEvaluateClassDirectories()
    }
}

def afterEvaluateClassDirectories() {
    tasks.withType(Test) {
        jacoco {
            afterEvaluate {
                classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
                    fileTree(dir: it, exclude:[
                            '**/R.class',
                            '**/R$*.class',
                            '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                            '**/BuildConfig.*',
                            '**/Manifest*.*'
                    ])
                }))
            }
        }
    }

    tasks.withType(JacocoReport) {
        reports {
            xml.isEnabled = true
            html.isEnabled = true
            html.destination = file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco")
        }
    }
}
```

I manage to individually generate the module level then use the below command:
*./gradlew :variantName:testDebugUnitTest*
This will generate reports under an /index.html.
However, I can no manage to get the coverage report with the percentages. Instead, I receive an empty index.html file with this text "No class files specified".
Could someone guide me please?